# Azure Sqldatabase or Virtual Private Server?

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, cloud, vps

I am new to Azure and I am currently exploring the possibility of migrating my database from a Virtual private server to an Azure hosted sql database. I can see the potential advantage of moving to azure, less maintenance, cloud hosted, cheaper.

My VPS i currently pay £36 every month, this is a fixed payment. However on Azure using the pricing calculator i can see that with a standard tier it would cost about £14, which is a huge saving. My only issue is that I have chosen the DTU. Now i am worried that for one month it may be fine, but for another month cost may spike. The reason why I have been hesitant to migrate is because I am fine with paying £36 a month knowing i can use less or more and i will still be at a fixed cost.

On the other hand - using azure with dtu, there is no guarantee that i may have the same cost each month, it may be potentially higher.

My question is can someone explain DTU for me and also is there a way where i can make sure my cost is low without having any surprise costs in the future?

Comment: Nothing like reading the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/purchasing-models?view=azuresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DTU-based SQL purchase models, a fixed set of resources is assigned to the database or elastic pool via performance tiers: Basic, Standard and Premium. This model is best for customers who prefer the simplicity of fixed payments each month, where the simplicity of pre-configured options is desired.

You need to first measure the resource utilization to check now much DTU is enough for you.

Measure the following utilization metrics for at least an hour so the calculator can analyze utilization over time to provide you the best recommendation:

- Processor - % Processor Time
- Logical Disk - Disk Reads/sec
- Logical Disk - Disk Writes/sec
- Database - Log Bytes Flushed/sec

Refer [this document](https://dtucalculator.azurewebsites.net/) to calculate the database resource consumption. Once you will get the output, calculate button to view your recommended Service Tier/Performance Level and DTUs on the same page.

Your consumption cost will be as per given image below:

[image]

You can also check your the pricing based on the your calculated DTUs [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/azure-sql-database/single/).